# Look for multiple occurences of text (partial match)

Tags: excel, vlookup, multiple-instances

I am struggling to solve the below problem:

I have a list of users who have attended various numbers of courses. Now I want to find which courses each person has attended and list them in a new sheet. Below is a picture of my sheet:

```
Names                                                                        | Courses
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Farnaz Hossein Zadeh, Elena Pak, Mehran Behzadi, Atefeh Ghorbani, John Smith | AP01
John Smith, Farnaz Hossein Zadeh, Tom green                                  | AP03
John Smith                                                                   | AP05
```

And I need to get:

```
F                      G       H
Farnaz Hossein Zadeh   AP01    AP03
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not quite possible with Excel formulas alone.

First, you need to clean up your data. Your can use Data > Text to columns to separate the comma-separated data. Then, make that data vertical so that you effectively have a list of pairs course-student. Then you can list unique courses by doing a pivot table on your data.